# When the response is as stupid as the question

Tags: irony

What do I say when someone asks a stupid question, then I give them a stupid answer, after that they complain "your answer sounds as if you're talking down to me".

How do I convey that "my answer is the same as your question" or "my answer is worth your question" or "equal" or?

What would a native speaker say in this case, in ironic way? Keep in mind, that this is my friend and allow ourselves being sarcastic easily :)

Comment: You reap what you sow. What goes around, comes around. You get what you paid for. You started it. There's really like a hundred, dude. Especially if this is between close friends and especially if you're allowed to use sarcasm. You can make up like a million things on the spot. Come on now.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that you were just **replying** [**in kind**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-kind):

> [Collins]
>
> If you respond in kind, you react to something that someone has done to you by doing the same thing to them.
>
> *They hurled defiant taunts at the riot police, who responded in kind.*

Answer (score 0):

> **[get what (one) deserves](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+what+(one)+deserves)**
>
> To be deserving of the bad things that happen to one, usually because
>   of one's past misdeeds.
>
> *Don't worry, that bully will get what she deserves—just give it
>   time.*
>
> Used to say that you think somebody has earned the bad things that
>   happen to them:
>
> *I’m not sorry he’s in prison. In my opinion, he got what he deserved.*

([idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+what+(one)+deserves))

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward "Stupid question -- stupid answer" would be fairly likely, if the tone (it is harsh) is OK in context.  If it is too harsh, then almost anything could be said, but nothing that would be idiomatic in general.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt and adopt a computer term: ***GIGO*** -- garbage in (your friend inputs her stupid question into you); garbage out (your output is a stupid and/or nonsensical answer).

GIGO, from the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gigo)

> abbreviation for garbage in, garbage out: used to say that if the
>   quality of data put into a computer is low, then the quality of the
>   information produced from that data will be low.

If you and your friend understand computer jargon, this adaption will be perfectly understandable.  If not, not.

Answer (score -1):

**stupid is as stupid does**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Stupid+Is+As+Stupid+Does)

> One's actions indicate one's level of stupidity (or intelligence). The
>   phrase was popularized by the film Forrest Gump. Of course that fool
>   backed his car into own house! Stupid is as stupid does! Stupid is as
>   stupid does, so judge her on her actions, not your first impression.